# Is there a way to use headphone controls to change attributes in my HTML audio player?

Tags: javascript, html

I took some code from a music player and I made a music player that I can listen to as an html file. It's all working fine, I just want to add something most other music apps have.

I realized that pressing the button on my wired headphones paused and played the music.

The problem I have is that most music players let you tap the button twice, or three times to skip and go back a song. I have no idea how to even search for "Pressing button on headphones to skip and go back osngs in html," no results show up that are useful.

I was also wondering if there was a way to run other types of functions with the headphone clicks, and if so, how to add those. (e.g. pressing the button on the wired earbuds 3 times to change an inline style attribute to, "style=color:black;background-color:white;")

I have no idea how to actually do anything with the buttons on my wired earbuds.

Here's some of my code I used:

```
    <div class="buttons">
      <div class="prev-track" onclick="prevTrack()">
        <img src="back.png" width="50px" class="fa fa-step-backward fa-2x">
      </div>
      <div class="playpause-track" onclick="playpauseTrack()">
        <img src="play.png" width="75px" class="fa fa-play-circle fa-5x">
      </div>
      <div class="next-track" onclick="nextTrack()">
        <img src="next.png" width="50px"  class="fa fa-step-forward fa-2x">
      </div>
    </div>
```

```
let playpause_btn = document.querySelector(".playpause-track");
let next_btn = document.querySelector(".next-track");
let prev_btn = document.querySelector(".prev-track");

let seek_slider = document.querySelector(".seek_slider");
let volume_slider = document.querySelector(".volume_slider");
let curr_time = document.querySelector(".current-time");
let total_duration = document.querySelector(".total-duration");

let track_index = 0;
let isPlaying = false;
let updateTimer;

// Create new audio element
let curr_track = document.createElement('audio');

// Define the tracks that have to be played

let track_list = [
  {
    name: "Skip this song",
    artist: "",
    image: "",
    path: ""
  },
  {
    name: "Choose an album",
    artist: "Than go back to the other song",
    image: "",
    path: ""
  },
];

// Load the first track in the tracklist
loadTrack(track_index);

function playpauseTrack() {
  if (!isPlaying) playTrack();
  else pauseTrack();
}

function playTrack() {
  curr_track.play();
  isPlaying = true;
  playpause_btn.innerHTML = '<img src="pause.png" width="75px" class="fa fa-pause-circle fa-5x">       ';
}

function pauseTrack() {
  curr_track.pause();
  isPlaying = false;
  playpause_btn.innerHTML = '<img src="play.png" width="75px" class="fa fa-play-circle fa-5x">';;
}

function nextTrack() {
  if (track_index < track_list.length - 1)
    track_index += 1;
  else track_index = 0;
  loadTrack(track_index);
  playTrack();
}

function prevTrack() {
  if (track_index > 0)
    track_index -= 1;
  else track_index = track_list.length;
  loadTrack(track_index);
  playTrack();
}

function seekTo() {
  let seekto = curr_track.duration * (seek_slider.value / 100);
  curr_track.currentTime = seekto;
}
```

Comment: take a look at this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaSession